# Is it possible GroupBy with loading nested navigation properties?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In my current work project, it became necessary to query grouped data from one table of the database to display it in a table in the UI. But I'd like to load nested navigation properties in this single query. How I can achieve it? *Is it possible?* (.NET 5, EF Core 5, C# 9)

Target class which described a table in a DB that data should be grouped:

```
public class XXX : YYY
{
    public int SmthEntityId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(SmthEntityId))]
    public virtual SmthEntity SmthEntity { get; set; }

    public int AnotherEntityId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(AnotherEntityId))]
    public virtual AnotherEntity AnotherEntity { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Field to bind executed value of aggregation function COUNT(*) per group (it is only my idea)
    /// </summary>
    [NotMapped]
    public int Count { get; set; } = 1;
    
    // etc.
}
```

Method of filtering, ordering, etc:

```
public IEnumerable<XXXDto> Filter(XXXFilter filter)
{
    var query = _context.XXX
        // These 'includes' as expected to have no effect on the result
        //.Include(x => x.SmthEntity)
        //.Include(x => x.AnorherEntity)
    ;

    if (filter.SmthEntityId.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(x => x.SmthEntityId == filter.SmthEntityId);

    if (filter.AnotherEntityId.HasValue)
        query = query.Where(x => x.AnotherEntityId == filter.AnotherEntityId);

    // It works fine, but after this part LazyLoading don't works
    **query = query.GroupBy(x => new { x.SmthEntityId, x.AnotherEntityId})
                 .Select(g => new XXX() {
                        SmthEntityId = g.Key.SmthEntityId,
                        AnotherEntityId = g.Key.AnotherEntityId,
                        Count = g.Count()
                    });**

    // Tries to move 'includes' here is impossible cos .Include() must be placed before .Select() => InvalidOperationException

    if (filter.SortDesc)
        query = query.OrderByDescending(x => EF.Property<object>(x, filter.SortColumn)).ThenByDescending(x => x.Id);
    else
        query = query.OrderBy(x => EF.Property<object>(x, filter.SortColumn)).ThenBy(x => x.Id);

    filter.Total = query.Count();

    query = query.Skip(filter.Skip).Take(filter.PageSize);

    return query.Select(x => DtoMapperHelper.GetXXXGrid(x));
}
```

DtoMapperHelper just is a static class with static methods to project entities to DTOs:

```
public static XXXDto GetXXXGrid(XXX entity)
{
    if (entity is null)
        return null;

    return new XXXDto
    {
        SmthEntity = GetSmthEntity(entity.SmthEntity), // dto
        AnotherEntity = GetAnotherEntity(entity.AnotherEntity), // dto
        Count = entity.Count
    };
}
```

Also maybe I'm wrong and is there a better way to achieve my goal here?

Comment: Can't reproduce your code, Please provide a minimal executable demo in your question.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I miss your comment cause didn't get any notification or skipped it...
I should try to use a given answer. Then I will complete my question. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I did some reproducible code example. Instead of grouping by id, group by navigation property. Keep in mind it probably won't be lazy loading, it will be eager loading. Cheers

```
var context = new Context();

await context.AddRangeAsync(new[]
{
    new Address
    {
        Street = "Main street",
        Users = new List<User>
        {
            new()
            {
                Name = "John"
            },
            new()
            {
                Name = "Adam"
            },
        }
    },
    new Address
    {
        Street = "Flower street",
        Users = new List<User>
        {
            new()
            {
                Name = "Ann"
            },
            new()
            {
                Name = "Monica"
            },
            new()
            {
                Name = "Alex"
            },
        }
    }
});

await context.SaveChangesAsync();

var result = await context.Users
    .GroupBy(x => x.Address)
    .Select(x => new {Count = x.Count(), Address = x.Key})
    .ToListAsync();

foreach(var x in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{x.Address.Street}: {x.Count}");
}

public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
            optionsBuilder
                .UseNpgsql("Host=localhost;Username=postgres;Password=postgrespw;Database=test;Port=49153");
    }
}
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; } = new();
}
public class Address
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; } = new List<User>();
}
```

Comment: I'll try it today. But yea, I think it will be eager loading too, will check a behavior in a console and then give a feedback to you. Thanks!